# .htaccess multiple domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one host for two domain. The first domain and its rules (aaaaa.com) are  working.

When I try to append rules of second one (bbbbb.com) send an Internal Error 500 message.

The goal is bbbbb.com should reply the content of bbbbb directory. Please help..

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 /errors/error404.html 
 Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteBase / 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)(?!aaaaa\.com)[^\.]+)\. 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ aaaaa/index.html?p=%1 [L] 

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bbbbb\.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bbbbb/%1 [R,L] 

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the apache configuration, I recommend you to use Virtual Hosts to achieve your purpose.

You should include this configuration in your /etc/apache2.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/aaaaa"
    ServerName aaaaa.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "/www/bbbbb"
     ServerName bbbbb.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Supposing that your web directories are stored in /www.

You can find the documentation here:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/